# Secure form submission

Tags: php, html, forms, security, submit

So I was just told that having this sort of thing visible whenever someone views the source on your front end is insecure:

```
<form action="http://www.somedomain.com/form.php" method="post">
```

Basically, that someone being able to see the php file that the form submits to is dangerous. Is this the case? If so, how do I make my visible source secure while still having the form submit to our hypothetical "form.php"?

Comment: Why would it be unsecure??

Comment: I don't know. But I made some comment about how I wasn't able to see where a different form submitted too and my boss (who is technically savvy but not a developer) said, "but seeing where it submits too is a major security risk". ...so I figured I'd come to the real experts and just make sure.

Comment: @NotMuchOfAProgrammer if your boss is worried about SQL Injection, then ensure you properly sanitize your user submitted data

Comment: It's not insecure. If your friends says so, (s)he wrong. The security should come from good clean code (sanitize the input in `form.php`). *Security through obscurity* should never be the end-goal.

Comment: @NotMuchOfAProgrammer here's how to explain this issue, explain to your boss what is the role of the form tag and why the action field is necessary, also explain to him that a safe form.php script shouldn't cause any problems and prove to him that your form.php is safe ... otherwise, let us know what are his or your fears regarding web app security

Comment: @NotMuchOfAProgrammer I think your boss is even less of a programmer. Either the form that your boss showed you doesn't submit *at all*, or the form processor URL is contained in some javascript. Either way, there is no way to get around the fact that you *have to* give the form processor URL to the client if you want them to submit *any* data to your form processor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first of all , php source code can't be viewed unless you restrict access to it via htaccess or other ways , secondly , your front-end source code must always be public because security issues aren't treated from the front to the back-end , thirdly , your php file's source can't be viewed like a css file or javascript code

if you want to restrict direct HTTP access to form.php , you could use .htaccess

i use this solution , some files are marked as somefile.php, but some util files are either stored in a folder or marked as utils.inc.php , so i make sure that i restrict direct access to inc.php files and allow everything else

Comment: In general I agree, but you did not stress enough that you really _cannot_ and _must not_ limit the client's knowledge on where it needs to send the data. OP's boss just does not know what he is saying. Even if, for some reason, the form will be submitted by other means and the default "`action`" will be ignored, anyone visiting the site will still be able to see where the data has been sent. Such "security issues" are not really security issues, he should rather put his effort in CSRF protection and such...

Comment: i agree, since I've developed intranet apps I wasn't really concerned about CSRF issues but your comment is important to take into account

Answer (score 1):

I personally do not see a problem with showing the page which the form submits too, because once the user submits his/her enteries, the `action=""` will re-direct the user to the page stated anyway, so either way they will see where they will end up. Whether in the URL bar or the form scripts.

Just ensure you sanitize the user-input data before passing it through your database.

Depending what your using for your Database Interaction; there will be functions available to protect you from injection

Answer (score 1):

Security by obscurity is a good policy in only very select, specific cases. But knowing where forms submit to – that's actually the nature of web forms. There's now way around that.

Even if the URL you submit to is somehow dynamically created for some kind of impression of security – just have a proxy between the browser and the server, and the entire HTTP dialogue is open to be read.